# Status light to check if API is running Android

Tags: android, status

I am making an app and the Google Maps API is a very depending part for me and I want to get a kind of light like this one: http://findicons.com/files/icons/1933/symbols/128/green_light.png
And when the Google maps API is down it changes to a red version of that picture.

greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others said, the Maps API should be present always, but anyway..
You can try to use any method from the API inside a try/catch block inside your app. A simple example:

```
mApiAvailable = true;
try {
    mMapsApi.checkVersion(); // I made up the method name
} catch (Exception ignored) {
    mApiAvailable = false;
}
```

Then for your ImageView (image names are also made up) [set the appropriate icon](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageResource(int)):

```
mIndicator.setImageResource(mApiAvailable ? R.drawable.api_on : R.drawable.api_off);
```

You could listen for some location event if such event exists to check the availability again and update the ImageView.

Comment: Thanks i will try it in a minute

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I think it's safe to assume the Google Maps API won't ever be down. But, to answer your question:

1. Find the pictures you want to use
2. Add them as drawables to your app project (java/res/drawable)
3. Add ImageView to your layout
4. Add the `android:src` attribute to your ImageView (in the layout's .xml)

Example:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/service_online" />
```

You can also change the ImageView's image source programmatically, more information on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2472175/3061857).